# C# ASP.NET CheckBox in UpdatePanel does not register click when clicked "during" update

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, updatepanel

Everything works as it should. I just find it annyoing that if you manage to click the checkbox "during" the update of the updatepanel it does not grab the click. Is there som workaround/fix for this or do I simply have to rethink my design and put the checkboxes in a different panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use AutoPostBack="True", checkbox will be working fine. Thanks

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Checkbox ID="chk" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:CheckBox>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic update shouldn't be on the same thread/task of the View (except some cases). Look for "c# async", you will find everything you need in Internet.